# Regex replacement with look behind and ignoring in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove all "'s" from text, except word "let's".

For example: "jerry's let's cake's" >> "jerry let's cake".

```
strText = Regex.Replace(strText, @"\b(?!let's)([a-z-]+)'s\b", @"$1");
```

- this works, but it takes long time on big texts.

```
strText = Regex.Replace(strText, @"\b(?!let's)(?<=[a-z-]+)'s\b", "");
```

- this one is not ignoring "let's"

What am I doing wrong in the second statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple trick you missed is using `\b` in the negative lookbehind :

```
(?<!\blet)'s
```

Working example: http://regexr.com?31g9c

Comment: \b(?<!\blet)'s\b - I'm not sure but maybe this one with \b works faster.

Comment: @Vildan - It might work faster, but note it will ignore `"Hello !'s"`, for example, because it needs a `\b` before the `'s`. If I had to optimize, I'd think the fastest would be `'s\b(?<!\blet's)` - the first thing it does is to look for `'s`, which should be fast.

Answer (score 3):

If this is *actually* what you need, it would be [wise to not use Regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) and do something like:

```
strText = strText.Replace(" let's ", " let''s ")
                 .Replace("'s", "")
                 .Replace(" let'", " let's");
```

Comment: +1 I agree Regex is probably not the best solution here. However, if the original string contained "let'" or "platelet's" this answer is not perfect and will need tweaking.

Comment: Updated, simple space before let :).  Yes, if the original string contained the invalid word let' then it won't work.  I hope that is an edge case for text.

Comment: What about `"let's let'@"`, or `(let's)`? A `\b` seems to be in order.

Comment: There are lots of edge cases that would have to contain *invalid* words.  If that is highly possible, this won't work, but I assume you have highly valid text.

Answer (score 1):

I also think you may write your own code.

```
private string myReplace(string text)
    {
        if (!text.Contains(' '))
        {
            return text.ToLower().Equals("let's") ? text : text.Replace("'s", string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            int index = text.IndexOf(' ');
            return myReplace(text.Substring(0, index)) + " " + myReplace(text.Substring(index + 1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, in this case it's probably best to go the old-fashioned way and walk the string, keeping track of where you are in the word "let's" and handling that especially.

Code (untested, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
StringBuilder stripped = new StringBuilder();
int letsPos = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < strText.Length; i++)
{
     char thisChar = strText[i];

     switch(letsPos)
     {    
         case -1:
             if(i == 0 || thisChar == ' ')
                 letsPos = 0;
             break;
         case 0:
             letsPos = (thisChar == 'l') ? 1 : -1;
             break;
         case 1:
             letsPos = (thisChar == 'e') ? 2 : -1;
             break;
         case 2:
             letsPos = (thisChar == 't') ? 3 : -1;
             break;
         case 3:
             letsPos = (thisChar == '\'') ? 4 : -1;
             break;
         case 4:
             letsPos = (thisChar == 's') ? 5 : -1;
             break;
         case 5:
             letsPos = (thisChar == ' ') ? 0 : -1;
             break;
     }

     if(thisChar == '\'' && 
         i+1 < strText.Length && 
         strText[i+1] == 's' && 
         (letsPos < 4 || (i+2 < strText.Length && strText[i+2] != ' '))
     {
         //skip the "'s"
         i += 2;
         letsPos = -1;
     }
     else
     {
         //not "'s" or we have a whole-word "let's"
         stripped.Append(thisChar);
     }
}

return stripped.ToString();
```